# How to change uploaded file name in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.7

I am using system.xml configuration to upload a file via backend. It works perfectly.

But I need to change the uploaded image's name to the current `store id`. How Can I? Now it is uploaded with its original name.

My `system.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <tabs>
    <restaurant translate="label" module="restaurant">
        <label>Upload Logo</label>
        <sort_order>999999</sort_order>
    </restaurant>
  </tabs>
  <sections>
    <restaurant_options translate="label">
      <label>Upload Logo</label>
      <tab>general</tab>
      <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
      <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
      <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
      <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
      <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
       <groups>
            <SAMPLE translate="label">
              <label>Upload Your Store's Logo</label>
              <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
              <sort_order>100</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
              <fields>
                    <ENABLED translate="label comment">
                        <label>Logo</label>
                        <comment>file types: jpeg, gif, png.</comment>
                        <frontend_type>image</frontend_type>
                        <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_image</backend_model>
                        <upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">theme</upload_dir>
                        <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">theme</base_url>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </ENABLED>
            </fields>
            </SAMPLE>
      </groups>
    </restaurant_options>
  </sections>
</config>
```

Please If any know a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create own backend model to store uploaded file. See following system.xml backend_model node:

```
<backend_model>restaurant/system_config_backend_image</backend_model>
```

app/code/community/YourPool/Restaurant/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image.php:

```
class YourPool_Restaurant_Model_System_Config_Backend_Image extends Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Image
{
    protected function _beforeSave()
    {
        $value = $this->getValue();
        if ($_FILES['groups']['tmp_name'][$this->getGroupId()]['fields'][$this->getField()]['value']) {

            $uploadDir = $this->_getUploadDir();

            try {
                $file             = array();
                $tmpName          = $_FILES['groups']['tmp_name'];
                $file['tmp_name'] = $tmpName[$this->getGroupId()]['fields'][$this->getField()]['value'];
                $name             = $_FILES['groups']['name'];
                $file['name']     = $name[$this->getGroupId()]['fields'][$this->getField()]['value'];
                $uploader         = new Mage_Core_Model_File_Uploader($file);
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions($this->_getAllowedExtensions());
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(TRUE);
                $uploader->addValidateCallback('size', $this, 'validateMaxSize');
                //here I added new name same as scopeId
                $ext    = explode('.', $file['name']);
                $ext    = array_pop($ext);
                $result = $uploader->save($uploadDir, $this->getScopeId() . '.' . $ext);

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::throwException($e->getMessage());
                return $this;
            }

            $filename = $result['file'];
            if ($filename) {
                if ($this->_addWhetherScopeInfo()) {
                    $filename = $this->_prependScopeInfo($filename);
                }
                $this->setValue($filename);
            }
        } else {
            if (is_array($value) && !empty($value['delete'])) {
                $this->setValue('');
            } else {
                $this->unsValue();
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```